# send HTML email with php correctly

Tags: php, html

I like to send HTML emails with PHP.
This is my code:

```
$send_to_email = $rowemail['Email'];
$Time = strtotime($rows['Time']);           
$to      = $send_to_email;
$subject = 'update'. date("d-m-Y H:i", $Time);
$message = '<div><h2>Dear Jelle,</h2>test 1</div>';
$headers  = 'From: info@test.nl' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

It only shows my html code directly, it doesn't change it to HTML code!
Like this:

```
<div><h2>Dear Jelle,</h2>test 1</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Does someone see this mistake?

Comment: well for one thing, your `\n`'s inside single quotes won't work; it must be double quotes.

Comment: However, those `\n`'s should be `<br>`'s since you're trying to use line breaks in HTML.

Comment: and the rest of your headers should also contain `"\r\n"`. See the manual on mail http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and look at the HTML examples. This and the above comments are relevant as to why your code is failing.

Comment: I don't know and it's not mine. You probably got those because you either didn't debug this yourself and/or did not read the manual on mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works!!!

```
$send_to_email = $rowemail['Email'];
$Time = strtotime($rows['Time']);           
$to      = $send_to_email;
$subject = "OZMO Storingsupdate ". date("d-m-Y H:i", $Time);
$message = "<div><h2>Dear Jelle,</h2>test 1</div><br/>";
$headers  = "From: info@ozmo.nl \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```